# django change something in template based on foreign key

Tags: python, django, templates, foreign-keys

I know it's very basic but I can't figure out how to resolve my problem.
I have a model like this:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    followed = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='followed')
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='followers')
```

my view:

```
def usersList(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/membres.html', {'users': users})
```

And here is what I want to do in my template:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% if request.user in user.followers.all %}
        I'm following you !
    {% else %}
        I'm not following you
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it's not working. I think I have to do something like this:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% if user.followers.filter(follower=request.user) %}
        I'm following you !
    {% else %}
        I'm not following you
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Try `user.followers.all()`

Comment: @NamanSogani: In templates, callables shouldn't need `()`.

Comment: What part isn't working? Does it print "I'm not following you" several times?

Comment: So I already pass user objects to template. It doesn't because I have to check this: if user.followers.filter(follower=request.user) something like this

Comment: @BoumTAC No this will not work..

Comment: I know this is why i ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to bypass my problem.

I add this method to my follow model:

```
def getListFollowed(self, user):
    relations = Follow.objects.filter(follower=user)
    liste = []
    for relation in relations:
        liste.append(relation.followed.username)
    return liste
```

I change my view this way:

```
def membres(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    f = Follow()
    relations = f.getListFollowed(request.user)
    return render(request, 'blog/membres.html', locals())
```

And i did this in my template:

```
{% if user in relations %}
    I'm not following you!
{% else %}
    I'm following you !
{% endif %}
```

I hope in can help some other who can have the same problem as me

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `users` object to template correctly...

```
def home(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'pages/test.html', {'users':users})
```

And HTML logic is correct it will work perfectly...

Comment: @BoumTAC Why it's not working on your side... It's working perfectly in my local...